# How to setup DbgLog with DirectShow

Tags: c++, debugging, directshow

I have an application using several DirectShow filters and I would like to get filters debug log, in order to trace down eventual issues. So far I have followed [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) manual, setting LogToFile attribute in the register. Anyway nothing is printed to the file.

Comment: This only works for filters in Debug-Build and only if the filters are really using the DbLog functions!

Comment: Does the standard DirectShow filter (like VMR9) use DbgLog?

Comment: No DbgLog is only a helper for your own filters. And even if it would use it, there is no Debug-Build of the VMR!

Comment: That's disappointing. Thank you for the information!